# Not able to use static library created using swift in Xcode 10.1

Tags: swift, static-libraries, static-linking, swift4.2, xcode10.1

I have created a static library using swift in Xcode 10.1 . Imported some swift files and build the library project with Release configuration for both simulator and generic device. Then used lipo command to merge both libXXX.a files as one and the final output has all architectures (armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64). Verified info with lipo command.

Now i want to use the libXXX.a file in some project. I dragged the file to the folder in Xcode and selected copy item if needed. But i am not able to use any function written in the file included in the library. I tried changing the framework search path and library search path to the directory of the .a file but same problem. How can i use the library in my project?